# MongoRepository: @Meta(maxExecutionTimeMs) not timing out

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I need to prevent a potentially long running aggregation query, on a multi-million document collectoon, from running past the REST client http timeout, to prevent leaving zombie queries on the server.

I added the Meta annotation with the indicated maxExecutionTimeMs value.
But it doesn't seem to be having any effect.

Being new to this annotation, what is the correct way to do this?

Alternatively is there a better way to do this globally, using spring mongo externalized configuration?  (I searched for other options, but most (e.g., maxTime) would require us to rewrite all of our (low-code) annotation based queries, into manually derived mongo operations queries.)

Mongo Server version: 4.4.22
org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.0.0.RELEASE

MongoRepository definition:

```
  @Meta(maxExecutionTimeMs = 1)   // TIMEOUT VALUE SELECTED TO VERIFY TIMEOUT
  @Aggregation({
      "{ $match : { $and :  [" +
      "   {'tenantId' :  ?0, 'productKey' :  ?1 }, " +
      "   { $or : [" +
      "       {'phoneNumber' :           {$in :  ?2}}," +
      "       {'secondaryPhoneNumber' :  {$in :  ?2}}," +
      "   ] }" +
      "] } }",
      "{ $sort : { 'updated' : -1 } }"
  })
  List<PII> getPiiByTenantProductAnyPhone(UUID tenantId, ProductKey productKey, String... phone);
```

I created a trivial aggregation, and applied an absurdly low timeout setting (1ms), to verify the desired time limit.

But when I ran the test, instead of seeing an expected timeout exception, I observed successful completion in excess of the configured timeout.

> {"@timestamp":"2023-07-07T15:44:45.729-04:00","@version":"1","message":"getPiiByTenantProductAnyPhone(): 65 msec","logger_name":"my.company.RecipientService","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-2","level":"INFO","level_value":40000,"requestId":"xxx","tenantId":"xxx","correlationId":"xxx"}

(Running the query manually in a mongo client on a much smaller data set, takes a couple of hundred milliseconds.  So I would expect this sample request to fail.)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been a transient problem caused by the mongo server internally cacheing the request results.  Subsequent attempts to trigger the timeout did succeed:

> {"@timestamp":"2023-07-07T18:03:46.492-04:00","@version":"1","message":"listRecipients failed due to message: operation exceeded time limit; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoExecutionTimeoutException: operation exceeded time limit exception: UncategorizedMongoDbException at: RecipientService.java:163","logger_name":"my.company.ServerException","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-10","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"requestId":"xxx","tenantId":"xxx","correlationId":"xxx"}
> {"@timestamp":"2023-07-07T18:03:46.493-04:00","@version":"1","message":"Internal Server Error","logger_name":"my.compnay.ControllerExceptionHandler","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-10","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"my.company.exceptions.ServerException: Encountered UncategorizedMongoDbException during listRecipients\n\tat my.company.controllers.RecipientController.listRecipients(RecipientController.java:56)\n\tat
> ...
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n","requestId":"xxx","tenantId":"xxx","correlationId":"xxx"}